# Auto refresh csproj when files in a particular folder are being added/removed

Tags: visual-studio-2012, appharbor, csproj

I have two projects:

1. A complex web site prototype consisting of only static files (content files, images and scripts)
2. A simple public Asp.net MVC 4 web site of a company

Company's using AppHarbor for their public website. As my prototype is static and has no particular dependencies I'd like to put it inside a folder of the public web site. Since MVC by default doesn't route existing files this scenario should work.

Therefore I'm publishing my prototype to local folder within local GIT repository of the public web site so it gets automatically synched to AppHarbor.

**The problem is** that public website web app is deployed to AppHarbor and as the service works it only deploys items that are part of web app project. This means that whenever I'm publishin my prototype, I should also edit my public web app's project file to add/remove items related to changes of the prototype.

### Question

Is there any automated way that would edit a csproj file and make appropriate changes so that my prototype would get deployed on AppHarbor?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this tool can help you: http://genproj.codeplex.com/
I was looking the same as you and just found it...